# Having issues making a camo-like, abstract procedural texture

Tags: texturing, shaders, procedural

I'm trying to recreate this similar to the camouflage look texture procedurally.

[image: The tex i want to remake]

It's just a sketch. Obviously, the handmade mistakes of my mouse aren't something I want on the texture.

I thought I could just use a *Noise* texture with a constant *Color Ramp* but I'm not happy with the results.

[image: Resulting texture]

This is my setup by the way:

[image: Node setup]

There are a bunch of dots that I can't get rid of and the white dots in the background aren't circular enough. Also, I want the blobs to be thicker and much rounder but every time I do that, more dots appear from letting up on the color ramp. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you want rounder white dots you can mix them in with a Voronoi texture + Color Ramp. To distort them a little mix the *Mapping* node with a *Noise* texture with the help of a *Mix (Light Path)* node. Set the *Fac* to a very small value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this satisfies your reference image, I recognize it looks similar to a camo texture (and if it satisfies your needs, maybe the word "camouflage" should be edited into the title), either way it may help future visitors and be a good starting point for your attempts:

[image]

[image]